# Is empty string valid XML?

Tags: xml, string

Is '' a valid piece of XML? 
Can '' insert into oracle xblob column or XML column from MSSQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not valid xml, but it can be inserted into an XML column in SQL Server 2005. Obviously with SQL Server 2005, you need to trade up the double quote for single quotes:

```
Insert Into MyTestTable(MyXmlColumn) Values('');
```

That works just fine - I just tested it and the insert was successful.

But Oracle does not allow empty XML. The expression `XMLType('')` will raise the exception "ORA-19032: Expected XML tag , got no content".

Comment: Don't you think this behavior from MSSQL 2005 is weired? Imagine you parse the data from that column to a XElement at dot net....

Comment: @CodeMelt: That's Microsoft for you - there's lots weird about their products.  If you wanted me to start a list of everything that was weird about MS products, I'd be here for eternity.

Answer (score 7):

No.  The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed) says a well-formed XML document satisfies:

```
document ::=  prolog  element  Misc*
```

where

```
element ::= EmptyElemTag
              | STag content ETag
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not an XML document - there needs to be at least one and at most one root element. (the XML declaration is optional if the encoding is UTF-8 and the version is 1.0 - production 22 of the XML recommendation). It is a valid XML *fragment* - either as an empty text node, or an empty range.

You'll have to define what 'piece of XML' means in your context.

Answer (score 1):

It's not valid xml.  Valid xml requires an xml declaration with encoding type and a root node.  Whether or not Oracle or SQL Server will accept it anyway is something you can check for yourself.

Comment: MSSQL column is fine with empty string and even a free text which is not in any XML style. I don't know how oracle to handle this. that is why I ask!

Comment: The XML declaration is actually not a strict requirement for valid XML.